# Is this the correct way to execute a url when an icon is clicked?

Tags: html

Not sure if using a div class is the best way to go about this. I am trying to have the URL load when the facebook icon is clicked.

```
<div class="social facebook">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without wrapping a URL into an "a" tag, you can do it like this;

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f" onclick="location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/'"></i>
```

Using an "a" tag you can use this;

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
```

Note: here I use font awesome icon tag "i"